# SPRESENSEで撮影した写真をLTE通信でサーバーに投稿したい

Tags: spresense, http

SPRESENSEで撮影した写真をLTE通信を用いてサーバーに投稿したいです。
現在、文字や数値はHTTP GETでサーバーに送信できているのですが、色々調べても写真の送信の仕方がHTTP POSTすること以外よく理解できません。
どのように記述すればよいか教えていただきたいです。
Arduino IDEを用いて開発しています。

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは。

具体的にどのようなサービス(サーバ)を使うかによっては投稿の仕方が異なるのでご所望の方法か自信はありません。

一般的なサイトのファイル送信フォーム(`<form method="post" action="example.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data">`)を使った場合は以下のサイトが参考になると思います。

https://qiita.com/KNaito/items/54b1bf61a3c678ca28b1

LteWebClient.inoのGETの部分を以下のようにすれば送信できるのではないかと思います。

```
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
 if (client.connect(server, port)) {
   Serial.println("connected");
   // Make a HTTP request:
   client.print("POST ");
   client.print(path);
   client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
   client.print("Host: ");
   client.println(server);
   client.println("Connection: close");
   client.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"xxx\"; filename=\"xxx\"");
   client.println("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
   client.println("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   client.println();

   /* バイナリファイルの送信コード */

 } else {
   // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
   Serial.println("connection failed");
 }
```

ご参考になれば幸いです。